# Code snippet inside @param Javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc

Is it possible to put a code snippet inside a parameter's JavaDoc? I tried the following, but the code snippet is not formatted as such in the generated docs.

```
/**
 * Description of method
 *
 * @param dataSourceProperties defines the properties of this datasource. At a minimum, the following should
 * be provided
 *
 * <pre>
 * {@code
 *     String driverClassName = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver';
 *     String url = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost/example';
 *     String username = 'root';
 *     String password = 'password';
 * }
 * </pre>
 */
```

Comment: your code would not compile, add a ";" to the end of the line

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is here, the code looks fine to me in Eclipse tool-tip at least. What are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. Try this one:

```
/**
 * Description of method
 *
 * @param dataSourceProperties defines the properties of this datasource. At a minimum, the following should
 * be provided
 *
 * <pre>
 * <code>
 *     String driverClassName = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
 *     String url = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost/example'
 *     String username = 'root'
 *     String password = 'password'
 * </code>
 * </pre>
 */
```